# Custom Regressor: GridSearchCV says 'get_params' not implement when inheriting from BaseEsitmator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, signal-processing

#### Hello,

#### **Thank you** for taking the time to look at this.

I am working on implementing a scikit-learn API version of this [blog post](https://nirpyresearch.com/partial-least-squares-regression-python/), the data is available [here](https://github.com/nevernervous78/nirpyresearch/blob/master/data/peach_spectra%2Bbrixvalues.csv). My custom class reproduces the authors results, but does not work with GridSearchCV.

Essentially, he implements partial least squares regression on some spectral data, with the optimal number of components being determined as the number components that yielded the lowest MSE. My attempt is shown below, I am able to replicate the authors MSE result for the optimal calibration, and the default parameters of the `__init__` below are set to those parameters. Note that I am inheriting from `BaseEstiamtor` and `RegressorMixin`.

```py
#download the .csv from the github repo from the blog post
#Creating df, shuffling, then creating `X` and `y`

df = pd.read_csv("nirpyresearch/data/peach_spectra+brixvalues.csv")
df = df.sample(replace=False, frac=1).copy()
y = df['Brix'].values
X = df[[i for i in list(df.columns) if 'wl' in i]].values
```

```py
class SavgolPLS(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    """My Regressor"""
    def __init__(self,  savgol_window = 17, savgol_polyorder = 2, savgol_deriv = 2, pls_components = 7 ):
        self.savgol_window = savgol_window
        self.savgol_polyorder = savgol_polyorder
        self.savgol_deriv = savgol_deriv
        self.pls_components = pls_components

    def fit(self, X, y):

        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)


        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y
        self.X_savgol_ = savgol_filter(X, self.savgol_window, self.savgol_polyorder, self.savgol_deriv)
        self.pls_ = PLSRegression(n_components=self.pls_components).fit(self.X_savgol_, self.y_)
        # Return the classifier
        return self

    def predict(self, X, apply_savgol = True):

        # Check is fit had been called
        #check_is_fitted(self)

        # Input validation
        X = check_array(X)
        if apply_savgol:
            X = savgol_filter(X, self.savgol_window, self.savgol_polyorder, self.savgol_deriv)
        pred_y = self.pls_.predict(X)
        return pred_y

    def score(self, y_pred):
        mse = mean_squared_error( y_true = self.y_, y_pred=y_pred,)
        return mse
```

I can now initialize the model and use  use `.get_params()` to get a dict containing the 4 parameters in the `__init__`.

```py
s_pls = SavgolPLS(pls_components=7)
s_pls.get_params()
```

Thus, `get_params()` seems to exist. . . which makes sense given that it was inherited from BaseEstimator. I can also use the `fit()` method to replicate the authors results.

```py
s_pls = s_pls.fit(X = X, y = y)
y_pred = s_pls.predict(X)

#This should be ~0.6566
s_pls.score(y_pred)
```

Why then, does applying GridSearchCV in code below generate the shown error?

```py
parameters  ={'savgol_window':[3,30], 'savgol_polyorder':[2,4], 'savgol_deriv':[1,3], 'pls_components':[2,15]}
clf = GridSearchCV(SavgolPLS, parameters, cv = 10)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Yields

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e20c1eabb4fa> in <module>
----> 1 clf.fit(X, y.ravel())

C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\dev_py37_tf\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    631         n_splits = cv.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
    632 
--> 633         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
    634 
    635         parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,

C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\dev_py37_tf\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     58                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     59                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 60                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     61     klass = estimator.__class__
     62     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<class '__main__.SavgolPLS'>' (type <class 'type'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

### Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a class to GridSearchCV, you should pass an instance: `clf = GridSearchCV(SavgolPLS(), parameters, cv = 10)`